# Linuxサーバー上の機能でサイトを常時開き、メッセージを受信したいです。

Tags: linux, centos

お世話になっております。初歩的な様で恐縮ですがご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

ユーザーに常にオープンにしているウェブサイトではシステム的に年間絶え間なく（24/7/365）でユーザーからのメッセージ等に対応しなければならない場合があると思います。

例えばユーザーから何らかのメッセージを受信用のサイト（www.xxxx.php）を立ち上げることによりシステム的に即時に受信し、自動的にデータベースに保存する様な作業などがあると思います。（前提としてそのサイトがメッセージを受信する為にはそのサイトが常に立ち上がっていなけばなりません。）

クライアント側でデスクトップを使用する側はその様なサイトを四六時中（24/7/365）で稼動できない場合があると思うのですが、その様な場合、サイト構築に使用した常に稼動しているサーバー会社のLinuxサーバーで対応できるものなのでしょうか。

つまり、Linuxサーバーの何らかの機能で上述のサイト（www.xxxx.php）を四六時中（24/7/365）開いている状態にし、ユーザーからのメッセージを常に受信することは可能でしょうか？（サーバーの一時的なシャットダウン等には対応できるものとして）

もし可能であれば、具体的なLinuxでの設定作業等、あるいは上述の目的実現のための他の方法等をお教え願いませんでしょうか。

環境：
Plesk バージョン：　17.0.17
構成名：　Plesk 12 Web Admin for Linux
PHP： 5.3.3
OS: ‪CentOS 6.9

Comment: ちょっと質問の意図が私には読み取れませんでした。Webサーバはユーザからのメッセージを常に受信できる状態になっているシステムです。「[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701)」にもなっている気もしますので、もう少し具体的になぜそれをやりたいのかを質問に含めてもらってもよろしいですか？

Comment: 「メッセージ」とは何を指していますか?  HTTPのリクエスト、HTTPでのフォーム送信、電子メール? 「常時稼働するウェブサーバを作るにはどうしたらいい」ということでしょうか

Comment: 大変恐縮です。ユーザーがデスクトップで開くサイトとは別に、常に開いていなければならない受信専用のサイトを稼動させることは可能でしょうか？

Comment: それがなぜ必要なのでしょうか？「受信専用のサイトを常時稼働させること」はあくまで「とある問題」を解決するためにご自身で考えた方法かと思います。「とある問題」に視点を移すことで別の解決方法が見つかる可能性があると思います。

Comment: 横からすみません。「ユーザーがデスクトップで開くサイト」というのが分かりにくいかと思います。あと「受信専用のサイト」というのは企業などが立てている「お問い合わせ」ページのことを仰っていますでしょうか？

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳ございません。ユーザーがウェブサイト上でアクションを起こすことにより、その情報が他システムに送信されます。
その他システムではそのユーザーに関連する情報をcsv形式でウェブサーバーに返信するのですが、そのcsv形式の情報をDBに保存するために必要な専用のサイトを常に稼動させたいです。

Comment: **ユーザーがアクションを起こすウェブサイト**と**情報が送信される他システム**と**csv形式の情報をDBに保存する専用のサイト**の関係性がはっきりしない(**情報が送信される他システム**から利用したいのか、**ユーザーがアクションを起こすウェブサイト**から利用したいのか、あるいは……)のでその点も含めてここまでのコメントでのやり取りを質問に反映していただけますか？

Comment: 皆様、ご多忙の中ご教授頂きまして大変感謝致します。整理をしつつ自分で取り組んでみようと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

サイトというのがWebサイト(もしくはWebページ)を指しているのであれば、クライアントからの要求に応じてブラウザに表示するページを随時返すのが **Webサーバ** です。

Webサーバのプロセスを稼働させておけばそれ自身が "窓口" となって適切な処理を行ってくれるので、「サイトやページを常時開いておく」という表現はあまり正しくありません。

(用意したページをお店の看板の様に出しっぱなしにしているわけではなく、注文があったらそのページだけを出前で届けてあげるイメージ)